# How to create realistic water blast in blender 2.79?

Tags: animation, particles, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to create a scene like this [image]

can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong create a fluid object sliding down a plane to make the water rise up just like in the image. I tried many different things like using control or obstacle to give some force to the fluid even adding some explosion to create something like this added some particles, crank up the resolution to 200 even added some smoke physics to the fluid particles... What am I doing wrong? I don't know if I should increase/decrease real world size just to create the illusion... I also watch other video tutorials but no one have thought about it yet...

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that your placing your hopes a little too high for Blender, or any fluid simulator existing today...  The amount of particles and data required for this is too high.

Comment: Do you still want an answer? I can give.